# Unless I start Management Studio with "Run as administrator", I get a Login Failure (Error 18456)

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows-7, ssms

I cannot connect to the SQL Server instance if I do not start management studio as a administrator.  I am running windows 7, SQL Server 2008, and Management Studio 10.0.  If I run as a normal user, the error I get is:

```
Cannot connect to ..

Additional information: login failed for user 'COMPUTERNAME\MyUserName'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error 18456)
```

for server name I have tried the following:

.
localhost
COMPUTERNAME

**Edit: SOLUTION HERE
https://serverfault.com/questions/130434/how-do-i-login-to-sql-server-without-having-to-use-run-as-administrator-when-st**

Comment: voted to close? don't you guys think you being a tad overzealous?  This may not be a coding question, but unless I get this answer, I won't be doing any coding in the near future.

Comment: All the close votes are for migrating this question to ServerFault. People there would be more knowledgeable on how to configure SQL Server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check how your SQL server authentication is configured. Most probably you have a login defined only for `BUILTIN\Administrator`s, but don't have one for `BUILTIN\Users` or for you Windows account.

Add a new login for `BUILTIN\Users` or your Windows account (`LOCAL_MACHINE\MedicineMan` :-)) and map the proper access rights. If you want to do DB admin rights, you should add login for your account. If you want just regular DB read/write, you can go for `BUILTIN\Users`.

Comment: @Slavo, @Franci I found that the directions were not very clear.  For this reason, I do not want to mark your question as accepted and award these points.  Franci did direct me to serverfault where I ultimately got a well written answer to my question.  I apologize if I could not understand your solution.  I'm sure that it is excellent.

Comment: @MedicineMan - your choice, but the answer you got on serverfault is exactly the same I gave you here.